# Meaning of Apache 2.0 License

Tags: maven, pom.xml

We are trying to use one of the maven plugins. Plugin has the below copyright in the header.

Apache License saying that we can use by changing the company name as we are customizing the file.

Can we use the Apache Plugin, but the group id is from com.***.****?

```
   Copyright 2015 <company name>

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
   use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
   the License at

   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
   WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
   License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
   the License.
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question. You should ask your company lawyer if you are unsure if you are compliant with the license text.

Comment: The first question which comes into my mind. Why do you need to change it? Have you created an issue into the appropriate jira project? Have you asked on the maven users mailing list? (And yes the legal question is something which does not belong to SO and should be answered by your company lawyer).